# Xpath How to test if self is the first child element of parent?

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have this XML fragment:

```
<seg><lb break="y" n="5">Curabitur eget lectus laoreet, facilisis ante in, suscipit nisl. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus in ullamcorper risus.<lb break="y" n="6"/>Duis arcu neque, tincidunt quis pulvinar non, pretium sed quam. Maecenas vitae felis<lb break="y" n="7"/>sed diam tempor porta hendrerit non eros. Vestibulum efficitur turpis eu<lb break="y" n="8"/>odio imperdiet. Quisque feugiat tincidunt ex.</seg>
```

In XSL 3.0 I want to replace the `<lb>` elements with `&#160;` only if the `<lb>` is **not** the first child element of `<seg>`.

I know that this doesn't work (but it gets the idea across):

```
<xsl:template match="lb">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@break='y' and ./parent::seg[/node()[1] != .]">&#160;</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise/>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Yet I don't know how to rewrite it to perform the test needed.

Demo [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eixh2x2).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the wanted result. Is an `lb` element sometimes empty (and simply to be replaced by a text node with `&#160;`) but sometimes it contains text? What is the replacement if text is contained. I general the verbal description sounds like you want to match on`seg/lb[not(. is ../node()[1])]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen `lb` is always self-closing.  Your solution for matching works, thanks. (I didn't know how to represent `&#160;` in a desired result on stack overflow and hoped the verbal explanation was enough).

Comment: By the way, rather use than `xsl:choose`/`xsl:when` with an empty `xsl:otherwise`, you can just use `xsl:if`

Comment: @ConalTuohy with Martin Honnen's `match` the whole problem goes away. That said, the `otherwise` was legacy code for a set of other conditions...

Comment: The answer depends on how the template is invoked. If the template matching the parent `seg` element  is applying templates to *all* its child nodes, then you could use `position() > 1` as your test. --- Note that your question is about the "first child *element*" but your attempt as well as Martin Honnen's suggestion look for the first *node*. Not the same thing.

Comment: The provided XML is not well-formed and placing it on a single line makes it unreadable. Please, respect your readers. Edit or expect disapproving reaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preceding-sibling` axis to see if the `lb` is the first child element of its parent. If the `lb` *is* the first child element of its parent then the `preceding-sibling` axis must have no elements on it, i.e. `preceding-sibling::*` is the empty set.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/seg"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="seg">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- possibly the test below should be "preceding-sibling::lb" ? -->
  <xsl:template match="seg/lb[@break='y' and preceding-sibling::*]">&#160;</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My XML was for simple example purposes: in real world application there is a lot of mixed content where `lb` could be nested in other elements. Your match would not work correctly in that case. This is why I'm insisting on first child in `seg`. Martin Honnen's suggestion targets it very specifically.

Comment: I updated my answer so it only applies to `lb` within a `seg`

Answer (score 0):

You could use these two templates:

```
  <!-- check for the first node() and if it is a lb with @break='y', skip it -->  
  <xsl:template match="seg/node()[1][self::lb[@break='y']]"/>
    
  <!-- check for every following node() and if it is a lb with @break='y', use >&#160;-->  
  <xsl:template match="seg/node()[position() gt 1][self::lb[@break='y']]">
    <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```